# How to test default value in enum using mockito and testNg

Tags: java, unit-testing, enums, mockito, testng

I have a third party enum class like this:

```
package se.api;
public enum InvestigationResultStatus {
  PENDING("PendingResult.rr"),
  NEW("NewResult.rr"),
  MODIFIED("ModifiedResult.rr"),
  FINAL("FinalResult.rr"),
  PRELIMINARY("PreliminaryResult.rr"),
  ADDITIONAL("AdditionalResult.rr"),
  REJECTED("RejectedResult.rr"),
  COMPLETE("Path.Results.InvestigationInformation.Complete"),
  UNDEFINED("");

  private final String languageKey;

  private InvestigationResultStatus(String languageKey) {
    this.languageKey = languageKey;
  }

  public String getLanguageKey() {
    return this.languageKey;
  }
}
```

and in my code I create enum for this class

```
package se.dto;
public enum InvestigationResultStatus
{
   PENDING,
   NEW,
   MODIFIED,
   FINAL,
   PRELIMINARY,
   ADDITIONAL,
   REJECTED,
   UNDEFINED
}
```

to map these api enum to my enum i created enum mapper:

```
package se.mapper;

import se.dto.InvestigationResultStatus;

public class InvestigationResultStatusMapper
{
  public InvestigationResultStatus mapOmResultStatusToNovaResultStatus(final se.api.InvestigationResultStatus investigationResultStatus){
    switch (investigationResultStatus){
      case PENDING:
        return InvestigationResultStatus.PENDING;
      case NEW:
        return InvestigationResultStatus.NEW;
      case MODIFIED:
        return InvestigationResultStatus.MODIFIED;
      case FINAL:
        return InvestigationResultStatus.FINAL;
      case PRELIMINARY:
        return InvestigationResultStatus.PRELIMINARY;
      case ADDITIONAL:
        return InvestigationResultStatus.ADDITIONAL;
      case REJECTED:
        return InvestigationResultStatus.REJECTED;
      case UNDEFINED:
        return InvestigationResultStatus.UNDEFINED;
      default:
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown InvestigationResultStatus: " + investigationResultStatus);
    }
  }
}
```

Now I want to test the InvestigationResultStatusMapper class default case path and throw IllegalArgumentException. I search and try it in many ways.But mosta of the examples are in using powermockito.but i want mackito with testNg.How can I test it.I try it using this,

```
@Test(expectedExceptions = { IllegalArgumentException.class })
  public void testMapOmResultStatusToNovaResultStatus_whenHaveDefaultValue_thenThrowIllegalArgumentException()
  {
    se.api.InvestigationResultStatus investigationResultStatusNewEnum = mock(se.api.InvestigationResultStatus.class);
    Whitebox.setInternalState(investigationResultStatusNewEnum, "name", "DEFAULT");
    Whitebox.setInternalState(investigationResultStatusNewEnum, "ordinal", "DefaultResult.rr");

    se.api.InvestigationResultStatus investigationResultStatusCosmic = mock(se.api.InvestigationResultStatus.class);

    when(investigationResultStatusCosmic.values()).thenReturn(
        new se.api.InvestigationResultStatus[] { InvestigationResultStatus.PENDING, InvestigationResultStatus.NEW,
            se.api.InvestigationResultStatus.MODIFIED, InvestigationResultStatus.FINAL, InvestigationResultStatus.PRELIMINARY,
            se.api.InvestigationResultStatus.ADDITIONAL, InvestigationResultStatus.REJECTED,
            se.api.InvestigationResultStatus.COMPLETE, InvestigationResultStatus.UNDEFINED, investigationResultStatusNewEnum });

    investigationResultStatusMapper.mapOmResultStatusToNovaResultStatus(investigationResultStatusNewEnum);
  }
```

Comment: I still have the error.Therefore i moved to powermock and mock it.not got any solution from mockito

Comment: As said: you wrote hard to test production code. The fact that you now start using powermock ... basically means that you fight the symptom, not the root cause. Rest assured: in the long run, you are more efficient by investing in  improving your designs, instead of using the more bizarre  mocking frameworks to work around the issues that are caused by your design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this I'm unabale to mock enum(final) class using mockito

```
 @BeforeClass
  public void setUp()
  {
    investigationResultStatusMapper = new InvestigationResultStatusMapper();
    investigationResultStatusNewEnum = PowerMockito.mock(InvestigationResultStatus.class);


    Whitebox.setInternalState(investigationResultStatusNewEnum, "name", "TEST");
    Whitebox.setInternalState(investigationResultStatusNewEnum, "ordinal", 9);

    InvestigationResultStatus[] investigationResultStatuses = Arrays
        .copyOf(InvestigationResultStatus.values(), InvestigationResultStatus.values().length + 1);
    investigationResultStatuses[investigationResultStatuses.length - 1] = investigationResultStatusNewEnum;

    PowerMockito.mockStatic(InvestigationResultStatus.class);

    PowerMockito.when(InvestigationResultStatus.values()).thenReturn(
        investigationResultStatuses);
  }

  /**
   * Test Method for {@link InvestigationResultStatusMapper#mapOmResultStatusToNovaResultStatus(InvestigationResultStatus)}
   * extend the InvestigationResultStatus enum for DEFAULT throw {@link IllegalArgumentException})
   */
  @Test(expectedExceptions = {
      IllegalArgumentException.class }, expectedExceptionsMessageRegExp = "Unknown InvestigationResultStatus: TEST")
  public void testMapOmResultStatusToNovaResultStatus_whenHaveDefaultValue_thenThrowIllegalArgumentException()
  {
    investigationResultStatusMapper.mapOmResultStatusToNovaResultStatus(investigationResultStatusNewEnum);
  }
```

Comment: Honestly, that is not a good self answer. You should at least add some explanations what exactly you did upfront. The fact that you just changed to PowerMock is not really obvious, and worse: as you said yourself: it doesn't answer your real question, as you didn't ask about powermock initially.

Answer (score 1):

you can create directly an instance in order to avoid mocks.

```
@Test(expectedExceptions = { IllegalArgumentException.class })
public void testMapOmResultStatusToNovaResultStatus_whenHaveDefaultValue_thenThrowIllegalArgumentException()
{

  InvestigationResultStatus investigation = new InvestigationResultStatus();
  investigation.mapOmResultStatusToNovaResultStatus(-10000);
   ....

}
```

Comment: next soft ,yes! but i want to test default case by passing value which are not in my enum.That's the case I mocked the Enum class.

Comment: I updated my answer, you can do that in order to throw IllegalArgumentException. @JayaniSumudini

Comment: next soft , I already have a one test case for test null,   @Test(expectedExceptions = { NullPointerException.class })
  public void testMapOmResultStatusToNovaResultStatus_whenHaveNull_thenThrowNullPointerException()
  {
    investigationResultStatusMapper.mapOmResultStatusToNovaResultStatus(null);
  }  but it return a NullPointerException.not a IllegalArgumentException.I want to test default case path.

Comment: :V sorry I don't understand .. what you mean

Comment: By default value? on your classes I don't see that you are putting some value by default, you need to test some value that was put. For example: class A { setEnum(Type.DEFAULT_VALUE)} so a test on class A,  A a  = new A();  a.getEnumValue();  so you will have a value by default.

Comment: next soft , you understand it wrongly. not a DEFAULY_VALUE.I mean default case path in switch case in InvestigationResultStatusMapper

Comment: Yes,so you need to add an assert equals in order compare them.  assertEquals(expectedValue, currentValue; on your case, assertEquals(InvestigationResultStatus.MODIFIED, investigation.getEnumValue())

Answer (score 0):

Wrong approach. First of all, the 3rd party enum has **9** entries, but your own enum has only **8**. So when your mapping code receives `COMPLETE` it will throw that exception! But if your own enum would have 9 entries, and you just map them 1-1 ... what is the point of using your own enum here in the first place? (there might be good reasons to have it, but at this point, it doesn't add much value).

Beyond that problem, you should do this completely different:

You put these **mappings** into a Map object. Then write a unit tests that uses `InvestigationResultStatus.values()` to acquire an array with all *valid* InvestigationResultStatus constants. You make sure that your map knows how to map all these valid constants (for example by checking that you get a non-null return value). Additionally, you might have one test for each 3rd party constant to check for the expected result.

The key point here is: unfortunately, enums might change over time. So you absolutely want to **know** when additional constants are added to the 3rd enum.

In other words: the java language respectively the compiler makes sure that there can't be "invalid" instances of that 3rd party enum. When you have `InvestigationResultStatus someEnumValue`, then it is 100% clear that: either `someValue` is null, or it is one of the constants from that enum. Nothing else is possible here! Thus: no need to expect, check or handle "invalid" values.